# Putting an equations' system on the left

Tags: equations, empheq

I'd like to start the equations' system from the left of the page and not in the middle. How can I modify this code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
d_x &= v_x \, T
\\
d_y &= v_y \, T
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: please always post a full test document but I assume you can use `fleqn` documentclass option for flush left equations

Comment: Hello @DavidCarlisle i edited my question; i tried with flushleft but it doesn't work.

Comment: It does work with me when I added `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}` to your posted example.

Comment: You should have a good reason for this. I don't see many (actually none).

Comment: Hello @egreg, i'm writing a my handout and i choose this style...i know that it is not the best, but for a personal use it is ok.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I wouldn't expect flushleft to work (that isn't what I suggested)

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle sorry, now i read the n and not h; your suggestion was like the one of hesham.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' env.

\begin{document}
\noindent
$\begin{cases}
  d_x = v_x \, T\\
  d_y = v_y \, T
\end{cases}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Mico thank you a lot fro your great reply.